# Statistics for changes in odds ratios

Tags: hypothesis-testing, odds-ratio

I am trying to come up with a statistical plan for comparing the odds ratio before and after an intervention (paired samples, not independent). What would be the best statistical method for doing this? Should I just look at the confidence interval overlap?

Another idea is just calculating change in odds ratio, but I'm not sure how to get confidence intervals for that.

Thanks for your help - I've looked at the similar questions and don't see anything that can help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is paired 2X2 experiment, yes? And you want to know whether the observed difference of the odds ratio from 1 is statistically significant? The answer to this question is a [McNemar test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test). Be careful using approaches that don't take into account the paired nature of the experiment; that is a common mistake for paired 2X2 experiments.

Comment: Yes, a 2X2 experiment. Thanks so much for the advice.